# LiveValidation test not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I downloaded LiveValidation to see if it would work for my site and for some reason my test code isn't working. Could anyone give a hand?

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="livevalidation.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
      <form name="example_form" action="#" method="POST">
        <input style="width:50px;" name="name" type="text" />
        <script>
            var f1 = new LiveValidation('name');
            f1.add(Validate.Presence);

        </script>

        <button class="button gray" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? I can imagine that browser can not find livevalidation.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First the field is set up to be a LiveValidation object, by passing in its id as the first argument.

You have passed in 'name' which is the value of name.
You need an id.

i.e.

```
<input id="name" style="width:50px;" name="name" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding an element to LiveValidation object id must be declared in field. 
This will do your code running.

`<input style="width:50px;" name="name" id="someIdName" type="text" />`

then add it object by Id name which u had specified :

```
 <script>
        var f1 = new LiveValidation('someIdName');
        f1.add(Validate.Presence);

    </script>
```